# Best successful unlock animations / design concepts

Tags: website-design, user-engagement

I'm building a section on my website where users are able to unlock items with 'tokens'. I want to ask the professional UX community what proven unlock animations / interactions really engage the user without feeling like a chore or a painful delay.

For example I was thinking a simple noise accompanied by perhaps a subtle white flash and maybe a 'luck dip' spin the wheel scenario with meaningful prize unlocks.

Fyi this particular site is focused at a mature professional community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a matter of choosing the right animation. Sure, a nice exciting animation is more entertaining to watch than a dull one. But this is only true for the first time(s) the animation is shown to the user. After that, especially when your application enhances productivity, the animation will get in the way of what the user wants to achieve.

Instead of trying to find the perfect animation, try asking yourself the following questions:

- how many times will the animation be played and in what time span? This is useful information for determining the length of the animation and how much attention it gets without obstructing the user.
- is it really necessary to put all user actions on hold during the animation? Maybe it's possible for the user to continue working while the animation is playing.
- what engagement are you trying to achieve? Engagement is a broad term. If you're specific you're better able to determine what user action is needed to serve a goal you specified.

Comment: In a strange way this answer has opened my eyes to the broader view of what UX is really all about. Thank you

Comment: Glad to be of any help :-)